# React - Error al abrir link en una pestaña nueva - props

Tags: reactjs, rutas, enlace, props

Código del route:

```
 <Route path='/:idurl' component={DATOS} />
```

Este es el código del link:

```
<Link
      to={{
            pathname: "/30dias",
            state: {
            fromNotifications: false,
            period: "month"
            }
          }}
 ></Link>
```

Con este código recupero los datos que envió al abrir el link:

```
const { idurl } = this.props.match.params    
const { period } = this.props.location.state
const { fromNotifications } = this.props.location.state
```

Al hacer clic en el link funciona sin problemas, pero al abrir el link en una pestaña nueva, me genera un error.

El error es generado por que los datos enviados al hacer clic en el link, no se envían y quedan en blanco.

Como podre solucionar este error o limitar para que no puedan abrir un link en otra pestaña nueva.

*Esto muestra al abrir el link desde una nueva pestaña*

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'period' of undefined
```

Desde ya. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Cuando dices en una nueva pestaña, te refieres recarga la pagina completamente o un modal?

Comment: Hola, no es modal, me refiero al hacer clic derecho en el link y elegir (abrir enlace en una pestaña nueva), saludos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No podras acceder a las propiedades de un router si abres otra ventana ya que reactjs maneja la transferencia de datos en memoria.

Si quieres enviar parametros a otra ventana, tendras que enviarlos en la URL y leer los parametros de la url utilizando `URLSearchParams` cuando cargue la pagina. Esto significaria que tendras que generar un link normal, o utilizar `windows.open`. 
Suponiendo que generes una url normal:

```js
 <a href="/home/about?numero=12345" target="_blank">Acerca de</a>
```

Entonces cuando cargue la pagina, obtener los parametros de la siguiente manera:

```
const params= new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
console.log(params.get('numero'));
```